# How to download files one by one using protractor and wait for each file to download before next download action?

Tags: node.js, selenium, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests

```
 it('download files', async () => {
         
            bt.download_files.each(async function (elem) {
                wait.waitForElementVisibility(elem);
                elem.click();
                len = browser.driver.wait(async function () {
                    var filesArray = glob.sync(dirPath + '**/*.+(xlsx|docx|pptx)');
                    if (typeof filesArray !== 'undefined' && filesArray.length > 0) {
                        return await filesArray;
                    }
                }, 60000).then(async function () {
                    return await fileSystem.getAllDirFiles(dirPath).length;
                }).then(function(len){
                    if(len === 6){
                        console.log('len is ',len);
                        expect(len).toBe(6);
                    }
                });

            });
        });
```

The issue in the above code is that it waits for the first file to download but as soon as it detects the first file in a folder it does not wait for the next files to download. I have getAllDirFiles() below

```
this.getAllDirFiles = function (dirPath, arrayOfFiles) {
        var files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);
  
        arrayOfFiles = arrayOfFiles || [];
  
        files.forEach(function (file) {
            if(fs.statSync(dirPath + "/" + file).isDirectory()) {
                arrayOfFiles = getAllDirFiles(dirPath + "/" + file, arrayOfFiles);
            }else {
                arrayOfFiles.push(file);
            }
        })
        return arrayOfFiles;
    }
```

Comment: because you need to do `for` loop instead of `each`

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov nope that also didn't help. Tried with for loop also, it shows the same behavior.